# Wait perl until sql query finish

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I am writing a perl script which will query data from MySQL and pushed to an array using while loop.Query will take more than 30(No specific time) mins because it contains 100k records to filter. script is exiting without success.
What command to wait until sql query finish?.

Comment: It sounds like there is a timeout on mysql server side. You will need to change that. Alternatively, try to change your query to pull fewer records at a time, use `LIMIT`, or add indexes for your specific query to your db. This is most likely not something that you can solve in Perl specifically.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question and use actual numbers. Not everyone here knows what a _lac_ (or is it _lakh_?) is.

Comment: thanks for updating me

Comment: lakh means something?  I assumed it was a typo for "lots."

Comment: @Hambone https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh